# C# Lambda expression -Help

Tags: c#, lambda

I am learning lambda expression and delegates.While i try to execute the following ,I am getting error at the line which is marked bold line. (*Error : Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Test.MessageDelegate' and 'lambda expression'*).Help me  to handle lambda expression.

```
namespace Test
{
    public delegate void MessageDelegate(string title,object sender,EventArgs e);
    class Program
    {
        static event MessageDelegate logEvent;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            logEvent = new MessageDelegate(OnLog);
            logEvent("title",Program.logEvent,EventArgs.Empty);
```

**logEvent += (src, e) => { OnLog("Some",src, e); };**

```
            Console.ReadKey(true);

        }

        static void OnLog(string title, object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (logEvent != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("title={0}", title);
                Console.WriteLine("sender={0}", sender);
                Console.WriteLine("arguments={0}",e.GetType());
            }
        }
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since logEvent has `MessageDelegate` as its event handler, you'd need the left hand of the lambda expression `(src, e)` to match the signature of `MessageDelegate`

Change to `(str, src, e) => OnLog(str, src, e)`

Comment: Suppose if i update my Main() as                            logEvent += (str, src, e) => { OnLog("One",Program.logEvent, EventArgs.Empty); };                          
logEvent += (str, src, e) => { OnLog("Two",Program.logEvent, EventArgs.Empty); };
(nothing is executed,how could i invoke it?)

Comment: I mean,consider Main() only has two  lines as stated in the above comment.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow what you want to do here. The "+=" assigns a listener to a certain event. When logEvent happens, invoke OnLog. That line of code itself does not raise the log event, it only says what to do *when* the event is raised. To raise the log event, you should do 'if(logEvent != null) logEvent("title", this, null);' (or whatever you want to pass)

Comment: As i already assigned a listerner, just i invoked it  as                                                                         if( logEvent!=null) logEvent(null,null,null); .